# "E721: do not compare types, use isinstance()" error

Tags: python, pep8

The python PEP 8 linter doesn't like this:

```
assert type(a) == type(b)
```

It tells me to use "isinstance()" instead. But to use `isinstance` I would have to do something like

```
assert isinstance(a, type(b)) and isinstance(b, type(a))
```

which seems much more unwiedly, and I don't really see the point.

Is the linter being wise in some way that I can't see? Or am I being wise in some way the linter can't see?

Comment: What is the context?  Is this in a test case? Why do want to assert that `a` and `b` have the same type, and intentionally break duck-typing?

Comment: From my point of view, if you want to check/assert that two vars have the same `type` then that usage is perfectly valid. The other, larger, question is that what type means in a dynamically typed language like python and why you need to check that.

Comment: according to my program's logic, one should have `type(a) == type(b)` at this point in the code, and I just want to assert that to see that everything is running smoothly---this is not some library where these vars might be subclassed, etc, just my own standalone piece of code

Comment: Note that `assert` is meant for debugging purposes or tests. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assert_stmt). If you actually want to test types, use try...except blocks.

Comment: In any way, consider using `type(a) is type(b)` (with the `is` operator).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From context added in the comments:

> according to my program's logic, one should have `type(a) == type(b)` at this point in the code, and I just want to assert that to see that everything is running smoothly

In this context, you should just ignore the linter because it's not suggesting anything useful to you. E721 was intended to warn people about issues via type-checks such as:

```
if type(a) == A:
    ...
```

The example above may be accidentally bugging the logical flow, by neglecting to consider the possibility that `a` is an instance of a subclass of `A`.

Comment: Yes it's what I suspected but `type(a) == A` where `A` is a type is something the linter could distinguish from `type(a) == type(b)` where `a` and `b` are vars. So it seems the linter isn't being as smart as it could (should?) be.

Comment: In my experience Python linters are blunt tools and implemented fairly naively.

Comment: I agree with this answer - the particular PEP8 guideline is not reasonable because `isinstance` will include checking for subclasses, which may be explicitly undesired by a program's logic. You may need a case where a certain type is exactly equal to some expected type, and a subclass would be a logical error regardless of duck typing or anything else. The real downside comes from flake8, autopep8 and similar tools, because now you have to annotate ugly `# noqa` pragmas or, even worse, change .ini files to completely ignore a flake8 rule that shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

## As a side note:

Never use `isinstance()` to validate types, one example is that `True` and `False` are considered instances of `int` so if you do something like this to check if a variable is an int:

```py
>>> isinstance(True, int) # the result would be True
True
```

but on the other hand:

```py
>>> type(True) # the type of True is bool
<class 'bool'>
>>> type(True) is int # now the result makes sense
False
```